# How to get Values from a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, ios-universal-links

I have an `NSString`. It is a URL I am getting when using Universal Links. I want to get **id** value from it. Is there any direct methods in SDK or do we need to use `componententsSeparated` String values?

Below is the NSString/URL:

> https://some.com/cc/test.html?id=3039#value=test

I want to get two things: "test" from test.html and "id" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSURLComponents` created from an `NSURL` or `NSString` of your URL.

From there you can use `path` to get the `/cc/test.html` part. Then use `lastPathComponent` to get `test.html` and finally use `stringByDeletingPathExtension` to get `test`.

To get the "id" value start with the components' `queryItems` value. Iterate that array finding the `NSURLQueryItem` with the name of "id" and then get its value.

Answer (score 1):

You could create `NSURLComponents` from URL string get parameters by calling `queryItems` method. It will return array of `NSURLQueryItem`

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"https://some.com/cc/test.html?id=3039&value=test"];
    NSArray *array = [components queryItems];
    for(NSURLQueryItem *item in array){
        NSLog(@"Name: %@, Value: %@", item.name, item.value);
    }
    NSLog(@"Items: %@", array);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make extension

```
  extension URL {              
      func getParamValue(paramaterName: String) -> String? {
          guard let url = URLComponents(string:self.absoluteString ) else { return nil }
             return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == paramaterName})?.value
      }
  }
```

Now you can call like below

```
let someURL = URL(string: "https://some.com/cc/test.html?id=3039&value=test")!
someURL.getParamValue("id") // 3039
someURL.getParamValue("value") // test
```